# What is the best method to swap words in a string

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Given the following string how would I swap the words right and left.

i.e. change

- "left" -> "right"
- "right" -> "left"

```js
let str = JSON.stringify({
  val: 4,
  right: {
    val: 7,
    right: { val: 9, right: null, left: null },
    left: { val: 6, right: null, left: null },
  },
  left: {
    val: 2,
    right: { val: 3, right: null, left: null },
    left: { val: 1, right: null, left: null },
  },
}, null, 2);

str = str.replace((/"left"/g), o => { return "right1" }); 
str = str.replace((/"right"/g), o => { return "left1" });

console.log(); 
console.log(str); 

str = str.replace((/"right1"/g), o => { return "right" });

console.log(); 
console.log(str); 

str = str.replace((/"left1"/g), o => { return "left" });
```

I'm thinking of using str.replace().

Comment: Define "best"...

Comment: Currently, I have this:   str = str.replace((/"left"/g), o => {
  return "right1"
 });
 str = str.replace((/"right"/g), o => {
  return "left1"
 }); 
 console.log();
 console.log(str);
 str = str.replace((/"right1"/g), o => {
  return "right"
 }); 
 console.log();
 console.log(str);
 str = str.replace((/"left1"/g), o => {
  return "left"
 }); However, this is verbose and doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: you should edit you current code into the question itself. It's hard to read in a comment. It looks like you are changing `left` -> `left1` and then `left1` -> `left`. Which would obviously be why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `replace`, use a temporary value:

```js
let str = '{"val":4,"right":{"val":7,"right":{"val":9,"right":null,"left":null},"left":{"val":6,"right":null,"left":null}},"left":{"val":2,"right":{"val":3,"right":null,"left":null},"left":{"val":1,"right":null,"left":null}}}';

function swap() {
  str = str.replace(/right/g, "temp");
  str = str.replace(/left/g, "right");
  str = str.replace(/temp/g, "left");
  console.log(str);
}

swap();
```

Comment: For new readers, this is an answer to the OP's original question. Please see the edits.

Answer (score 1):

Don't stringify (or if starting from a string, parse it first). Work with the object itself and you can easily write a recursive function to do this:

```js
var original = {
  val: 4,
  right: {
    val: 7,
    right: { val: 9, right: null, left: null },
    left: { val: 6, right: null, left: null },
  },
  left: {
    val: 2,
    right: { val: 3, right: null, left: null },
    left: { val: 1, right: null, left: null },
  },
};

function swapLR(obj) {
    if (!obj || (obj.left == null && obj.right == null)) {
        return obj;
    }
    var tmp = swapLR(obj.left);
    obj.left = swapLR(obj.right);
    obj.right = tmp;
    return obj;
}

console.log(original);
console.log(swapLR(original));
```

You can then `stringify` it back at the end if you need to.

Comment: I actually edited that stringify in there to make it readable, but preserve the old sentiment. His old format had that whole object poorly formatted as a single string.

Comment: @m0meni: far enough, but that's pretty much you changing the OPs intent entirely. I agree it was horrible to read previous (and the first thing I did when it was still a string was format it)

Comment: for this approach you need a balanced structure.

Comment: @NinaScholz: Fixed.

Comment: I was primarily concerned about how to swamp strings.

Comment: @user10109: And the answer is *don't*. You can write code to swap strings in a JSON string and it'll work right up to the point somebody sends an object like: `{ left: { text: "I hope this works alright" },...}`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use string manipulation, keep/parse as object and swap the properties:

```js
function swapLeftRight(obj){
  //use object deconstruction to create left and right variables, 
  //and assign them to the opposite name
  let {left:right, right:left} = obj;
  //Assign the new values
  obj.left = left, obj.right = right;
  //Use recursion if the properties are not null
  if(obj.left) swapLeftRight(obj.left);
  if(obj.right) swapLeftRight(obj.right);
}
var data = {
  val: 4,
  right: {
    val: 7,
    right: { val: 9, right: null, left: null },
    left: { val: 6, right: null, left: null },
  },
  left: {
    val: 2,
    right: { val: 3, right: null, left: null },
    left: { val: 1, right: null, left: null },
  }
};
swapLeftRight(data);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of the function that you can pass to [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) is the `match`.

You could update your code to use an alternation to match either "left" or "right" and flip the values.

[`(?:left|right)`](https://regex101.com/r/a2lrzQ/1)

```
let replaced = str.replace(/(?:left|right)/g, o => {
  return o === "left" ? "right" : "left";
});
```

Note that using this regex you would also match "left" in "alefta". If you want to match left or right only you could use a word boundary `\b`:

[`\b(?:left|right)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/a2lrzQ/2)

```js
let str = JSON.stringify({
  val: 4,
  right: {
    val: 7,
    right: {
      val: 9,
      right: null,
      left: null
    },
    left: {
      val: 6,
      right: null,
      left: null
    },
  },
  left: {
    val: 2,
    right: {
      val: 3,
      right: null,
      left: null
    },
    left: {
      val: 1,
      right: null,
      left: null
    },
  },
}, null, 2);

let replaced = str.replace(/(?:left|right)/g, o => {
  return o === "left" ? "right" : "left";
});

console.log(replaced);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use a placeholder, and then replace the placeholder,

```js
let str = JSON.stringify({
  val: 4,
  right: {
    val: 7,
    right: { val: 9, right: null, left: null },
    left: { val: 6, right: null, left: null },
  },
  left: {
    val: 2,
    right: { val: 3, right: null, left: null },
    left: { val: 1, right: null, left: null },
  },
}, null, 2);

let newStr = str
  .replace('right', '$')
  .replace('left', 'right')
  .replace('$', 'left')

console.log(newStr)
```

Alternatively, you can parse the JSON, and recursively swap nodes because you actually have a binary tree on your hands.